# Install geopandas in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, gdal, geopandas, fiona

Sorry if this is a repeat question, But I am new to Python and trying to install Geopandas in Pycharm.
My python version is 3.7.2.

1. I have tried the conventional way of installing library in pycharm through project interpretor.
2. I have also tried `pip install geopandas`

Both show same error.

> A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Please provide steps to follow wrt Pycharm if possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Geopandas's own install instructions](https://geopandas.org/install.html), the *recommended* way is to install via [conda](https://conda.io/en/latest/) package manager, which you can obtain by using the [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) or [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) Python distributions:

```
conda install geopandas
```

If, however, you have a *Very Good Reason* you can't use `conda`, and absolutely need to use `pip`, you should try installing GDAL first (`pip install GDAL`), and then checking if the `gdal-config` command is in your path (i.e. that you can access it via the terminal). Then you can try installing again from either PyCharm directly or via the command line.

If you can't get it installed from PyCharm and need to specify `GDAL_VERSION` (which you can get with `gdal-config --version`), you'll probably need to install from the command line, where you can set this variable either with an `export` or directly in the same invocation:

```
GDAL_VERSION=2.4.2 pip install geopandas
```